# i have a php variable that i have to display the length of as a 3 digit number that is right aligned

Tags: php, string, variables, string-length

this is a really noob question I guess, but I am very new to php and have no idea how to even begin this one, basically I have a set of $vars that I have to display the length of as a 3 digit number that is right justified.

Any pointers as to how to do this?

Many thanks for all your help.

Comment: this is the result of an unclear question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should take care of what you just described in your comment:

```
echo str_pad(strlen("hello"), 3 , "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

This will return

```
005
```

Comment: Thanks, but i need the value the total of characters in a variable, so $var = "hello" // 5 characters

I need to display this as 005

Comment: @EricEdward And what if it's more than 999 characters?

Comment: The variables are fixed in this case, so they will never go over 999, however I do see your point and is something worth considering in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer lies within PHP documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php

From their example:

```
<?php
$input = "Alien";
echo str_pad($input, 10);                      // produces "Alien     "
echo str_pad($input, 10, "-=", STR_PAD_LEFT);  // produces "-=-=-Alien"
echo str_pad($input, 10, "_", STR_PAD_BOTH);   // produces "__Alien___"
echo str_pad($input, 6 , "___");               // produces "Alien_"
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The printf version:

```
printf("%40d", 123); //                                      123
```

40 chars right justified